# Why the login from Facebook SDK for WP automatically login after the first login?

Tags: windows, facebook, windows-phone-8

I created a app with facebook sdk http://facebooksdk.net/, for Windows Phone 8.
I ran the app and do a login but after i do a logout, and when i try do a login it automatically do the login with the user i used in the first time, why?? and if i want to use a different user, can´t? i try to see the code in https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk
but didn´t conclude nothing.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the Cookies. After the Logout() method, call:

```
await new WebBrowser().ClearCookiesAsync();
```